# How to add a variable inside a double quoted string

Tags: javascript

```
var testStr='World';
tUserBlock.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:alert("Hello" + testStr)');
```

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm trying to add a variable to .setAttribute onclick event, but I'm not quite sure what the correct syntax is to add the variable into the quote? The above alert doesn't show.

Comment: DO NOT USE SET ATTRIBUTE TO ADD A CLICK HANDLER! BAD BAD BAD. You should be using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var testStr='World';
tUserBlock.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:alert("Hello '+testStr+'")');
```

However this is a poor way of binding click events to elements. Instead, look into the `element.addEventListener` method - that is the preferred way of binding. There's various reasons for this - one is that you are not limited to just one event of each type (as you are with your current approach). Another is that it keeps code out of your mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way of binding events (no need to use `setAttribute`):

```
var testStr='World';
tUserBlock.onclick = function() { alert("Hello" + testStr) };
```

If you still insist on your original way, this is the way of doing it:

```
var testStr='World';
tUserBlock.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:alert("Hello ' + testStr + '")');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var testStr='World';
tUserBlock.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:alert("Hello '+testStr+'")');
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and I haven't changed anything:

```
<button class="tUserBlock">click me</button>

<script>
  var tUserBlock = document.querySelector('.tUserBlock');
  var testStr='World';
  tUserBlock.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:alert("Hello" + testStr)');  
</script>
```